# UIBezierPath: byRoundingCorners: doesn't work

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I'm trying to round just 2 corners of a button. This is the code I am using.

```
let bezierSelectAllPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: selectAllButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.BottomRight.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight), cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0))

        let maskSelectLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskSelectLayer.frame = selectAllButton.bounds
        maskSelectLayer.path = bezierSelectAllPath.CGPath
        selectAllButton.layer.mask = maskSelectLayer
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the end

```
[selectAllButton.layer addSublayer:maskSelectLayer];
```

instead of

```
selectAllButton.layer.mask = maskSelectLayer
```

and you can set your button's corners like this :

```
UIBezierPath * bezierSelectAllPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:button.bounds
                                            byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                  cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0)];
```

Comment: if I add a sublayer I get some veeeeery strange results. The button goes beyond the screen. I am already doing the second thing you posted with union. For some reason compiler throws an error if I use | operator.